# visual studio cordova appp error while building in releasing mode

Tags: cordova, visual-studio-cordova

I'm facing a problem (see screenshot below) while building an app on my device in Visual Studio Cordova.

Before using a keystore in my project, it works fine in debug mode and release mode and makes an APK file in bin folder.

When I use a keystore it does not create an APK. How can I solve this?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: What version of Cordova are you targeting?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem
the workaround for me was signing the generated APK manually with this script:

```
cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_55\bin"
jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore /myKeystore.keystore /android-release-unsigned.apk myAlias
```